# Delphi XML Bindings objects - exporting nodes

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe

I have the following scenario: using XML Data Bindings, I have an object created from schema A, and a different object created using schema B. However, schema B **imports** schema A in order to define children nodes of the A type.

So, right now I have:

- unit1, `objectA` (from schema A)
- unit2, `objectB` (from schema B), `objectA` (from schema B which imports schema A)

The `unit2.objectA` class is, of course, incompatible with `unit1.objectA`.  The definition in unit2 is also different, because it doesn't include some namespace attributes (this is important: I think these are implicit because the parent node also have them.)

And this is my problem: I can do lots of stuff given that these are just `IXMLDocument` objects, but I want to be able to create `unit1.objectA` from `unit2.objectA`.

My initial thought was that one should be able to export nodes from a document, and that there should be an option to make this exported node "kosher" according to the correct schema (so, a node of type A inside a document B should export and validate against the schema A.) I understand that this may be wishing too much, so my question may be rephrased:

**How can I** export a node from a `IXMLDocument` object into a new `IXMLDocument` object, while adding/overriding namespace attributes (`xmlns`, `xmlns:xsi`, `xsi:schemaLocation`) in the exported node / document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a really tricky issue. Resorted to use low level DOM functions from my XML library and a lot of elbow grease; had to export the wanted fragment, and manually adjusted schemas and namespaces, then reformatted everything.